# Column in pageBlockTable is not rendering

Tags: visualforce

I got stuck in a scenario. I have a `pageBlockTable` and in that I have 3 columns with a `dataTable` in the 3rd column. I have a `commandLink` in that column, and when I click on that all records are rendered, but I need to render only that particular record's `dataTable`.

Please have a look at the Visualforce page. Can you let me know how to render according to a particular record?

```
<apex:page controller="repeatcontroller" > 
 <apex:form > 
  <apex:pageBlock > 
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CallplanAccounts}" var="status" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="13" columnsWidth="3"> 
    <apex:column headerValue="Name"> 
     {!status.acc.Name}   
    </apex:column> 
    <apex:column headerValue="Status"> 
     {!status.acc.Active__c}   
    </apex:column> 

    <apex:column > 
     <apex:commandLink action="{!Callstatus}" id="renderit" > 
      CallString<apex:param name="cmid" value="{!status.acc.id}" assignTo="{!approveid}" /> 
     </apex:commandLink> <br/> 

     <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!visible_comment =='show'}" > 
      <apex:dataTable value="{!status.acc.Call_Strings__r}" var="cm" > 
       <apex:column headerValue="Callstring name" > 
        {!cm.name} 
       </apex:column> 
       <apex:column headerValue="Origianl values" > 
        {!cm.Original_CallString__c} 
       </apex:column> 
       <apex:column headerValue="Updated values" > 
        <apex:outputField value="{!cm.Updated_CallString__c }" > 
         <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton" / > 
        </apex:outputfield> 
       </apex:column> 
      </apex:dataTable> 
     </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:column> 
   </apex:pageBlockTable> 
 </apex:pageBlock> 
 </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: did you try pringint visible_comment on the page? I believe it is not coming as 'show'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't have a `reRender` tag in your command link. Without that after clicking a whole page is just reloaded. Try to insert `reRender="XXX"`. Something like this:

```
<apex:column > 
    <apex:commandLink action="{!Callstatus}" id="renderit" reRender="myPanel"> 
    CallString<apex:param name="cmid" value="{!status.acc.id}" assignTo="{!approveid}" /> 
    </apex:commandLink> <br/> 

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!visible_comment =='show'}" id="myPanel">
    // your stuff    
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:column>
```

Comment: This was my original thought as well, but I am concerned this may not work in his situation. The issue I am concerned with is the fact that your outputPanel with id of myPanel will actually be duplicated along the page multiple times since it is nested in a pageBlockTable. I am not really sure how to handle this. I would probably rerender the entire pageBlockTable depending on performance. Are you sure this works with the ID on the outputPanel inside the column?

Comment: Added rerender as you said. but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code, it appears to me that the variable "visble_comment" is not associated with every record( Would be easy if you could post the controller code as well). And if that the case, the output is but obvious.You may need to use a [WRAPPER class](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) to associate "visible_comment" with every record.

Comment: Heres is the callstatus method..

Comment: I think you forgot to add the Code :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the rerender attribute on the command link will solve the problem. I am more concerned with callStatus function which on the controller should read the approveid and populate the arraylist status.acc.Call_Strings__r. 
 From an UI perspective, i think your output would really be clumsy with this design. I would take the datatable outside the pageblock and make it display only on clicking the command link. That way the panel would open on the right side of the current datatable.
So the real issues which are problematic are rerender attribute and your callstatus function which should repopulate the arraylist everytime. Put a system debug on the function and it should solve the problem
Buyan